# Can I overload operator new to avoid an using an abstract factory?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, operator-overloading

I was wondering if it was possible to return specific implementations of an interface without using an abstract factory, so I put a simple use case.

Now, aside from being a little unorthodox, the test case produces the expected output.

```
allocating implementation
interface ctor
implementation ctor
5
implementation dtor
interface dtor
freeing implementation
```

However, I have never seen anyone do things this way before, so I was wondering if there was anything fundamentally wrong with this approach.

**edit:** The purpose of this is to hide platform specific code from the caller without using the abstract factory or pimpl design patterns.

**MyInterface.h**

```
class MyInterface
{
public:
    MyInterface();
    MyInterface(int);
    virtual ~MyInterface();

    void *operator new(size_t sz);
    void operator delete(void *ptr);

    virtual int GetNumber(){ return 0; }
};
```

**MyImplementation.cpp**

```
#include "MyInterface.h"

class MyImplementation : public MyInterface
{
    int someData;
public:
    MyImplementation() : MyInterface(0)
    {
        cout << "implementation ctor" << endl;
        someData = 5;
    }

    virtual ~MyImplementation()
    {
        cout << "implementation dtor" << endl;
    }

    void *operator new(size_t, void *ptr)
    {
        return ptr;
    }

    void operator delete(void*, void*){}

    void operator delete(void *ptr)
    {
        cout << "freeing implementation" << endl;
        free(ptr);
    }

    virtual int GetNumber() { return someData; }
};

/////////////////////////
void* MyInterface::operator new(size_t sz)
{
    cout << "allocating implementation" << endl;
    return malloc(sizeof(MyImplementation));
}

void MyInterface::operator delete(void *ptr)
{
    // won't be called
}

MyInterface::MyInterface()
{
    new (this) MyImplementation;
}

MyInterface::MyInterface(int)
{
    cout << "interface ctor" << endl;
}

MyInterface::~MyInterface()
{
    cout << "interface dtor" << endl;
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    MyInterface *i = new MyInterface;

    cout << i->GetNumber() << endl;

    delete i;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be good to know what your motivations are.

Comment: I think new operator should know the type of object going to be constructed.

Comment: @steven using platform specific implementations in a way that is completely hidden from the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a `MyInterface` on the stack this is obviously going to cause problems since there won't be enough memory at that location for the implementation.

Even if you always allocate it on the heap, it smells like undefined behavior since you re-construct over a half-constructed base class (one could argue this violates the "two distinct objects must have different addresses" clause).

Unfortunately I can't tell the real problem you're trying to solve so I cant' give you specific answer(s) about that.

Comment: true, and without hiding the constructors, which I need, I guess I'm out of luck.